# LINQ sql expression to exclude data that is present in other table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to write a LINQ query to return a list of username which are not yet assigned.
My `Usernames` table looks like this:

```
Id | Username  
1  | user.1
2  | user.2
3  | user.3
```

The `Assignments` table holds just the username, next to some other data:

```
Username | SomeOtherData
user.1   | foo
user.3   | bar
```

The LINQ query that I am trying to write should return `user.2` in the above example.

My query, unfortunately, returns too many users and I am not sure how to tweak my LINQ expression:

```
from u in Usernames
    join a in Assignments on u.Username equals a.Username
    where u.Username != a.Username
    select u
```

Adding the Distinct() method filters down the result set but it still returns usernames which are assigned:

```
(from u in Usernames
    join a in Assignments on u.Username equals a.Username
    where u.Username != a.Username
    select new { u }).Distinct()
```

What would be the best way to tweak these LINQ expressions, to return only those usernames which are not in the assignments table?

Comment: Both queries return zero rows - inconsistent with your question. You might need to share more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a left join using DefaultIfEmpty. Something like as follows:

```
from u in Usernames 
join a in Assignments on u.Username equals a.Username into userAssignments
from ua in userAssignments.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ua == null
    select u
```

Answer (score 4):

You are joining the two tables on username, that is not going to return you the usernames that are not common in both the table. You need to select the usernames which are not present in Assignment table.

```
Context.Usernames.Where(x=> !Assignments.Select(y => y.Username).Contains(X.Username));
```

Another way of writing the same query :

```
Context.Usernames.Where(x=> Assignments.All(y => y.Username ! = x.UserName));
```

Comment: +1. I just think that using `All` extension instead of `Select` and `Contains` will be cleaner - `Context.Usernames.Where(x=> Context.Assignments.All(y => y.Username ! = x.Username));`

Comment: Yes, agreed. Looks cleaner this way. (y)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!
If I were to filter on another field (e.g. Country), how would I add this criteria to the expression? Let's say, I would like to have only those unassigned users where Country == 1. Adding it like so wouldn't return any records: `Context.Usernames.Where(x=> Assignments.All(y => y.Username ! = x.UserName && y.Country == "1"));`